# Exponential regression: calculating p-value and F significance

Tags: regression, anova, descriptive-statistics, nonlinear-regression, excel

I have a set of independent data and dependent data $(X,Y)$, where I would like to do an exponential regression to obtain its p-value and significant $F$ (already obtained $R^2$ and also the coefficients through mathematical calculation).

Often an exponential data, $y=be^{mx}$ will be converted first to a linear data, $\ln y = mx + \ln b $. Then a linear regression will done on the converted data, obtaining its p-value etc. Assume we use a statistical tool such as Excel's Analysis ToolPak: Data Analysis : Regression, it will produce a result such as below,

[image]

I believe the p-value and Significant $F$ value above is representing the converted linear data and not the original exponential data.

Questions:

1. What is the approach/steps used by Excel to get the p-value and Significant F value for the converted linear data as shown in the statistic output in the image above? It is not clear in their help page or website.
2. Can the p-value and Significant F could be mathematically calculated for **exponential regression** without using a statistical tool? Can you assist to point me to the right link if this has been answered before.

Spent a week on the internet to study this but unable to find the right answer.

Comment: There is no $F$ statistic for non-linear regression.

Comment: Thanks @mpiktas. I am new to statistics. Excuse me if my question were elementary. Where can I learn more that non-liner regression does not have F statistics. I am reading Basic Econometrics, 4th Edition by Damodar N. Gujarati. Does non-linear regression have p-value? Kindly suggest me any books if it has been well explained there. Will go to my library to read it. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have fixation on non-linear regression? The mathematics behind it is a bit more complicated, so introductory econometrics textbooks do not cover it. Wooldridge's Econometric analysis of cross-section and panel data has nice chapter on non-linear regression and statistical tests associated with it.

Comment: Fixation? LOL. Am a PhD student but from Engineering field. Currently working on an interpolation prediction strategy. So happen my data has an exponential trait. Though I managed to get the regression coefficients, then the equation and R squared values, I learn R squared alone is insufficient to test a hypothesis (Null or otherwise).Several write-ups point to that direction.The p-value is said to be an important statistical significant testing parameter.This is my last piece of jigsaw (after learning there is no F statistics for non-liner regression). Will rush to library now.

Comment: If you are from engineering field, then more practical books might be of service. Modern applied Statistics with S comes into mind. Try searching this site for reading lists, there were some questions where person asked about statistics books for non-statisticians.